My discord music bot dont working. Not receiving commands
I tried to develop a discord music bot instead of using another bots. Here`s my code:
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const {
        prefix,
        token,
} = require('./config.json');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const { CLient, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],
});
const queue = new Map();

client.once('ready', () => {
        console.log('Ready!');
});

client.once('reconnecting', () => {
        console.log('Reconnecting!');
});

client.once('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Disconnect!');
});

client.on('message', async message => {
        console.log('Message recieved')
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

        const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

        if (message.content.startsWith(`!play`)) {
                execute(message, serverQueue);
                return;
        } else if (message.content.startsWith(`!skip`)) {
                skip(message, serverQueue);
                return;
        } else if (message.content.startsWith(`!stop`)) {
                stop(message, serverQueue);
                return;
        } else {
                message.channel.send('You need to enter a valid command!')
        }
});

async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
        const args = message.content.split(' ');

        const voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a voice channel to play music!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT') || !permissions.has('SPEAK')) {
                return message.channel.send('I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!');
        }

        const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
        const song = {
                title: songInfo.title,
                url: songInfo.video_url,
        };

        if (!serverQueue) {
                const queueContruct = {
                        textChannel: message.channel,
                        voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
                        connection: null,
                        songs: [],
                        volume: 5,
                        playing: true,
                };

                queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

                queueContruct.songs.push(song);

                try {
                        var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
                        queueContruct.connection = connection;
                        play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
                } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                        return message.channel.send(err);
                }
        } else {
                serverQueue.songs.push(song);
                console.log(serverQueue.songs);
                return message.channel.send(`${song.title} has been added to the queue!`);
        }

}

function skip(message, serverQueue) {
        if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!');
        if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send('There is no song that I could skip!');
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function stop(message, serverQueue) {
        if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!');
        serverQueue.songs = [];
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function play(guild, song) {
        const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);

        if (!song) {
                serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
                queue.delete(guild.id);
                return;
        }

        const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.playStream(ytdl(song.url))
                .on('end', () => {
                        console.log('Music ended!');
                        serverQueue.songs.shift();
                        play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
                })
                .on('error', error => {
                        console.error(error);
                });
        dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
}

client.login(token);

In config.json i have only token variable and prefix var, but i dont use prefix var now.
When I running this script my bot goes online in discord, but doesn't receive commands, I set up a test output but it turns out the message processing function doesn't work. What do you think the problem might be?
As a command prefix i use "!".

Welcome to SO! Please share your error messages and debugging details.

Did you enable the messageContent intent for your Bot on the Developer Portal?

Check your discord,js version. if it's above v13, try using client.on('messageCreate', async message instead of client.on('message', async message
